# Is the socket accept method blocking in this situation

Tags: java, sockets, threadpool

Just a short and sweet one. I am trying to make a chat client so I have a threadpool managing the socket connections on the server. If I use:

```
    while(true) {
        thrdPool.execute(new ServChatSocket(servSocket.accept(), InOutMan));
    }
```

Will this block `ServChatSocket`'s from being created and added to the pool until it receives a connection, add a weird broken `ServChatSocket` to the pool with unexpected results, or throw some kind of repeated error until it receives an inbound connection?

Should I use an if statement in the while block to check if there is an object ready to connect before passing to the `thrdPool`? Something like:

```
    while(true) {
        if(s = servSocket.accept()) {
            thrdPool.execute(new ServChatSocket(s, InOutMan));
        }
    }
```

On top of preventing aforementioned errors (if there are any) would this be considered better, cleaner code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple matter of order of evaluation.

```
thrdPool.execute(new ServChatSocket(servSocket.accept(), InOutMan));
```

is nothing but a normal function call. There is no magic inside Java that tries to detect that when you write this, it has to do with starting thread. No, the job of execute() method is to start threads within itself, but that's only within itself.

So here, you call execute() with a parameter. This parameter is:

```
new ServChatSocket(servSocket.accept(), InOutMan)
```

so it must be evaluated before execute() can be called.

It's a constructor that has two parameters who need to be evaluated before the constructor is called. One of these parameters is

```
servSocket.accept()
```

which is a method calls that blocks until a client connects and a socket connection is accepted.

So yes, it will block. No thread creation before it's ready, no error.

> On top of preventing aforementioned errors (if there are any) would
>   this be considered better, cleaner code?

if() can only evaluate boolean expression, so your example won't work. And more to the point, there is no if(). When you call accept(), either you obtain a valid Socket instance in response, or your program dies trying and there is no code execution when it's dead.

But you should probably call accept() first, store the Socket in a variable, and execute() then. In terms of execution that's the same thing as putting everything in only one line. But the fact that you're asking these questions shows that our human brains are a bit challenged with understanding these lines and reading them correctly. You're not alone. It's just simply clearer to decompose the sequential steps in multiple instructions.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this block ServChatSocket's from being created and added to the pool until it receives a connection

Yes.

> add a weird broken ServChatSocket to the pool with unexpected results

No.

> or throw some kind of repeated error until it receives an inbound connection?

No.

> Should I use an if statement in the while block to check if there is an object ready to connect before passing to the thrdPool?

No. `ServerSocket.accept()` never returns null.